# Dialog.ElicitSlot is running in a loop how to end and start dialogue again in alexa ?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

```
function delegateSlotCollection(){
 console.log("current dialogState: "+this.event.request.dialogState);
   if (this.event.request.dialogState === "STARTED") {
     var updatedIntent=this.event.request.intent;
     this.emit(":delegate", updatedIntent);
   } else if (this.event.request.dialogState !== "COMPLETED") {
     console.log("in not completed");
      if(this.event.request.intent.slots.customername.value) {
            let prompt = "Please Tell Me your Item name  ";
            let reprompt = "";
            console.log("Printed");
            this.emit(':elicitSlot', 'item', prompt, reprompt); 
      }

   } else {

     return this.event.request.intent;
   }
}
```

After running this code it ask for customer name after that it elicits item value and after that when i enter item value it goes in a loop and again and again ask item value how to break this ?

output json :-

> "directives": [
>                 {
>                     "type": "Dialog.ElicitSlot",
>                     "slotToElicit": "item"
>                 }           ],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function delegateSlotCollection(){
 console.log("current dialogState: "+this.event.request.dialogState);
   if (this.event.request.dialogState === "STARTED") {
     var updatedIntent=this.event.request.intent;
     this.emit(":delegate", updatedIntent);
   } else if (this.event.request.dialogState !== "COMPLETED") {
     console.log("in not completed");
     if (this.event.request.intent.slots.item.value) {
         this.emit(":delegate");
     }
      else if(this.event.request.intent.slots.customername.value) {
            let prompt = "Please Tell Me your Item name HELLO  ";
            let reprompt = "";
            console.log("Printed");
            this.emit(':elicitSlot', 'item', prompt, reprompt); 
      }

   } else {

     return this.event.request.intent;
   }
}
```

Okay Found This Solution It Worked